# Client Validation Not Working in kendo UI Core

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui

my problem is client-side validation doesn`t work in .net core. I use the kendo library. I don`t know where is the problem.

this is my code:

this my code but it`s doesn`t show a required Message

[image]

[image]

Comment: when you want to use data validation for asp.net core, it requires to use data submit, it's not triggered by js event, such as onblur event...

Comment: see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0